# Spring Integration - pass Map into processor class

Tags: spring-data, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration along with Spring JPA.
I need to read data from 5 tables and send it to one processor class for complex processing.

The 5 tables are: UserExecution, UserExecutionDetail, Master, Inventory, Store.

I needs bits and pieces of data from each of these table. I do not want to create a POJO to store the DB data, and instead want to store the DB data in a map.

The map will then be passed to a processor class for complex processing.

**What should the code in the processor be like? I have attached the code I have used below.**

[image]

**Processor class:**

```
public class DataProcessor {
@Transformer
public void processUserData(Message<Map<String,String>> msg) {
    //Some complex logic using userDetailsMap
}
```

}

**Retrieving DB data:**

```
    class ServicetoDBAdaptor {

@Autowired
UserExecutionDetail userExecutionDetail;

@Autowired
UserExecution userExecution;

@Autowired
Master master;

@Autowired
Inventory inventory;

@Autowired
Store store;

@Autowired
UserExecutionDetailRepository userExecutionDetailRepository;

@Autowired
UserExecutionRepository userExecutionRepository;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ServiceActivator
private void readFromTable1_UserExecutionDetail(Message<UserExecutionDetail> msg) throws Exception {
    userExecutionDetail = userExecutionDetailRepository.findById(msg.getPayload().getId());
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ServiceActivator
private void readFromTable2_UserExecution(Message<UserExecutionDetail> msg) throws Exception {
    userExecution = userExecutionRepository.findById(msg.getPayload().getId());
}
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ServiceActivator
private void readFromTable3_Master(Message<UserExecutionDetail> msg) throws Exception {
    master = userExecutionRepository.findById(msg.getPayload().getId());
}
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ServiceActivator
private void readFromTable4_Inventory(Message<UserExecutionDetail> msg) throws Exception {
    inventory = userExecutionRepository.findById(msg.getPayload().getId());
}
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@ServiceActivator
private void readFromTable5_Store(Message<UserExecutionDetail> msg) throws Exception {
    store = userExecutionRepository.findById(msg.getPayload().getId());
}
Map<String,String> userDetailsMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
userDetailsMap.put("ID",msg.getPayload().getId());
userDetailsMap.put("ExecutionStatus",userExecution.getStatus());
userDetailsMap.put("ExecutionDetailStatus",userExecution.getDetailedStatus());
userDetailsMap.put("TotalOrders",master.getTotalOrders());
userDetailsMap.put("OrdersCompleted",inventory.getOrdersCompleted());
userDetailsMap.put("StoreStatus",store.getStoreStatus());

return userDetailsMap;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem though? Why that doesn’t work for you?

Answer (score 0):

try transformer class as below..

```
@Transformer
public SomeResponse processUserData((Message<?> message) {
// use message.getPayload() and cast it to map.
    //Some complex logic using userDetailsMap
}
```

and call this method from the flow as below. you can keep the 'processUserData' method in the same flow class.

```
.transform(this)
```

Comment: The method for `transform()` can’t return `void`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Artem, I just copy pasted the method signature., i just corrected the answer.

Comment: Well, even that `Message<Map<String,String>> msg` is going to work just because he claims that his `readFromFiveTables()` method returns a `Map`. The incoming message into the next handler is just an outgoing message from the previous handler.